# SIGABRT error when clicking a switch in the simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, sigabrt

I have been working on an iPhone app Cruzia and was wondering if anyone knows why I am getting this SIGABRT error in the simulator whenever I click one of the switches in the options menu of my game. Here is my 15 main file with the error commented off.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "CIAAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CIAAppDelegate class]));
//Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
    }
}
```

For reference, here is my ViewController.m

```
#import "CIAViewController.h"

@interface CIAViewController()


@end

@implementation CIAViewController



-(IBAction)press {
    cruzia.hidden = 0;
    textarea.hidden = 0;
    playbtn.hidden = 1;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 1;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 1;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 1;
    back.hidden = 0;
    soundlbl.hidden = 1;
    music.hidden = 1;
    sound.hidden = 1;
    musiclbl.hidden = 1;
    cruzia.text = @"Play";
    textarea.text = @"Hello! You are playing the game of Cruzia!";
        if (clicked == 1)  {
                CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
                CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
                soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"click",                     CFSTR ("electronic click.wav"), NULL);
                UInt32 soundID;
                AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
             }
}


-(IBAction)press2 {
    cruzia.hidden = 0;
    textarea.hidden = 0;
    playbtn.hidden = 1;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 1;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 1;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 1;
    back.hidden = 0;
    soundlbl.hidden = 1;
    music.hidden = 1;
    sound.hidden = 1;
    musiclbl.hidden = 1;
    cruzia.text = @"Tutorial";
    textarea.text = @"Welcome! You are watching the Cruzia tutorial!";
    if (clicked == 1)  {
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"click",                     CFSTR ("electronic click.wav"), NULL);
        UInt32 soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
}

-(IBAction)press3 {
    cruzia.hidden = 0;
    textarea.hidden = 0;
    playbtn.hidden = 1;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 1;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 1;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 1;
    back.hidden = 0;
    soundlbl.hidden = 0;
    music.hidden = 0;
    sound.hidden = 0;
    musiclbl.hidden = 0;
    cruzia.text = @"Options";
    textarea.text = @"Hello! You have clicked Options. To control other areas of the gane, go to the settings app and open the Cruzia addon.";
    if (clicked == 1)  {
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"click",                     CFSTR ("electronic click.wav"), NULL);
        UInt32 soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
}

-(IBAction)press4 {
    cruzia.hidden = 0;
    textarea.hidden = 0;
    playbtn.hidden = 1;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 1;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 1;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 1;
    back.hidden = 0;
    soundlbl.hidden = 1;
    music.hidden = 1;
    sound.hidden = 1;
    musiclbl.hidden = 1;
    cruzia.text = @"Training";
    textarea.text = @"This is the training area. You can improve your Cruzia skills here!";
    if (clicked == 1)  {
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"click",                     CFSTR ("electronic click.wav"), NULL);
        UInt32 soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
}

-(IBAction)returnpress
    {
    cruzia.hidden = 0;
    textarea.hidden = 0;
    playbtn.hidden = 0;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 0;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 0;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 0;
    back.hidden = 1;
    soundlbl.hidden = 1;
    music.hidden = 1;
    sound.hidden = 1;
    musiclbl.hidden = 1;
    cruzia.text = @"Cruzia";
    textarea.text = @"";
    if (clicked == 1)  {
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"click",                     CFSTR ("electronic click.wav"), NULL);
        UInt32 soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    textarea.hidden = 1;
    playbtn.hidden = 0;
    tutorialbtn.hidden = 0;
    optionsbtn.hidden = 0;
    trainingbtn.hidden = 0;
    back.hidden = 1;
    soundlbl.hidden = 1;
    music.hidden = 1;
    sound.hidden = 1;
    musiclbl.hidden = 1;
    cruzia.text = @"Cruzia";
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateSettings:)
                                                name:
     NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    [self setupDefaults];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    [super viewDidUnload];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) setupDefaults {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


    NSString *violenceValue = [defaults stringForKey:kViolenceMode];

    if ( violenceValue == nil ) {
        NSString *pathStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *settingsBundlePath = [pathStr stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.bundle"];
        NSString *finalPath = [settingsBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root.plist"];

        NSDictionary *settingsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
        NSArray *prefSpecifierArray = [settingsDictionary objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];


        NSString *violence_identifier, *isPushNotifyOn;

        NSDictionary *prefItem;

        for (prefItem in prefSpecifierArray) {
            NSString *keyValue = [prefItem objectForKey:@"Key"];
            id defaultValue = [prefItem objectForKey:@"DeafultValue"];

            if ([keyValue isEqualToString:kViolenceMode])
            {
                violence_identifier = defaultValue;
            }
            else if ([keyValue isEqualToString:kPushNotifications])
            {
                isPushNotifyOn = defaultValue;
            }

            NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                                  violence_identifier, kViolenceMode, isPushNotifyOn, kPushNotifications, nil];

            [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
            [defaults synchronize];

        }

    }

}



@end
```

And here is my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>


int clicked;

#define kViolenceMode @"violence_identifier"
#define kPushNotifications @"isPushNotifyOn"

@interface CIAViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *cruzia;
    IBOutlet UILabel *textarea;
    IBOutlet UIButton *playbtn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *tutorialbtn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *optionsbtn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *trainingbtn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *back;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *music;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *sound;
    IBOutlet UILabel *soundlbl;
    IBOutlet UILabel *musiclbl;
}

- (void) setupDefaults;

-(IBAction)press;
-(IBAction)press2;
-(IBAction)press3;
-(IBAction)press4;
-(IBAction)returnpress;
-(IBAction)music;
-(IBAction)sound;
@end
```

If anyone knows why I am getting this error, I would greatly appreciate it if they could tell me.
-George

Comment: Do you have an IBAction for that switch?

Comment: yes. -(IBAction)returnpress;

Comment: Can you try to comment out the the whole if block in press method and see if it is still gives you the error so you can debug if that's where the error coming from

Comment: Can you add a symbolic breakpoint so you can see where the exception is being thrown from?

Comment: Also, why are your IBOutlets ivars rather than properties?

Comment: BTW, you should remove your observer either in viewDidDisappear or dealloc -- viewDidUnload is no longer called.

Comment: Thank you @danielbeard however I do not know exactly why they are ivars because i was just following the tutorials I found. If you could tell me how to fix it I would be very pleased!

Comment: also @rdelmar I tried viewDidDissapear but XCode asked for an animation. Exactly how to I use viewDidDissapear would be great to know!